# How to load vuetify 3 to inertiajs(laravel 8)

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3, inertiajs, vuetifyjs3

how do i load vuetify 3(alpha) into my app while using inertiajs (vue3 installed), currently my app.js look like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    
    setup({ el, app, props,plugin }) {
        
        const vuetify=  createVuetify(
        )
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(vuetify)
            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

i really need help.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I'm facing same problem. I don't really know how to setup vue 3 + vuetify + inertiajs